# Preventing decimals with NSNumberFormatter

Tags: ios, string-formatting, nsnumberformatter

I have an `NSNumberFormatter` which I'm trying to use to generate a whole number of GBP (£) from an `NSNumber`. I keep getting two decimal places regardless of which incantation I try. My code is:

```
NSNumberFormatter *fmtCurrency = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[fmtCurrency setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[fmtCurrency setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:FALSE];
[fmtCurrency setCurrencyCode:@"GBP"];
[fmtCurrency setCurrencySymbol:@"£"];
txtTotal.text = [fmtCurrency stringFromNumber: result.Bill ]; // this is an NSNumber
```

Comment: i think getting the intvalue will remove the decimal part

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I think you want to call setMaximumFractionDigits with zero.

```
NSNumberFormatter *fmtCurrency = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[fmtCurrency setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[fmtCurrency setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:NO];
[fmtCurrency setCurrencyCode:@"GBP"];
[fmtCurrency setCurrencySymbol:@"£"];

NSNumber* myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:12.34];
NSString* myString = [fmtCurrency stringFromNumber:myNumber];
NSLog( @"the number is %@", myString );

[fmtCurrency setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
myString = [fmtCurrency stringFromNumber:myNumber];
NSLog( @"now it's %@", myString );  


2011-07-25 01:05:39.823 FormatterTest[841:707] the number is £12.34
2011-07-25 01:05:39.824 FormatterTest[841:707] now it's £12
```

Answer (score 13):

You can try the following

```
[fmtCurrency setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:NO];
[fmtCurrency setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
```

or

Get `intValue` from the `NSNumber` as suggested by @Praveen

Comment: Thanks, by setting minimumFractionDigits and maximumFractionDigits to zero I got what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

You need to extract the [intValue](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) from [NSNumber](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4

```
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove all the NSNumberFormatter (which is quite intensive) and just do:

```
txtTotal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"£%d", result.Bill.intValue];
```

Answer (score -2):

format string to two decimals... (was what i was searching) adapted...

```
            float distance = //distance with many decimals...;

            NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
            [numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

            //new distance with two decimals
            NSNumber* myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:distance];
```

good luck