# Showing Doubles in Labels with AND without the decimal-point

Tags: ios, swift, double, textfield, decimal-point

**To check the best answer, scroll down to Paulw11's answer.**

(I apologize for any english mistakes, it's not my 1st language)

I need to solve this problem in order to continue to develop my app.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGzzK.png), I got a screenshot. (I know, it's ugly, I'm setting the constraints.)

The problem is: even when the number is a integer, it still shows as a rational. (ex.: 4 appears as 4.0, 16 as 16.0)

What I want is:

- When the number in the textfield is integer, I want it to appear without the decimal-point. ( 4 appear as 4, 16 appear as 16)
- When the number in the textfield is rational, I want it to appear with the decimal-point that belong to it. (4.2 appears as 4.2, 2.5 as 2.5)

What I don't want to happen:

- Round any number. This will ruin the math. As I said, 4.22 needs to be 4.22 . But 4.0 needs to be only 4 .

I'll be very grateful for any help, thank you.

Comment: Could you post some code please?

Comment: This is probably what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6813241/2687360

Comment: No, @Asdrubal, I don't want to round it.

Comment: This one is in Objective-C, isn't it? As I'm new to programming, it's even harder to... ''translate'' a language to another. And I also didn't find any solution.

Comment: @Bienemann, I will simplify:

`var deltaValue: Double = 0 // var for the math
@IBOutlet weak var deltaValueS: UILabel! //label to hold the value
deltaValue = (valueBint! * valueBint!) - (4 * valueAint! * valueCint!)
deltaValueS.text = "∆ é " + deltaValue.description`

Comment: maybe convert the integer to a string and check the last two elements? If it ends with .0 then you remove those two elements from the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `%g` formatting option:

```
deltaValueS.text = String(format:"∆ é %g",deltaValue)
```

- For 4.0 this will give "∆ é 4"
- For 4.123 this will give "∆ é 4.123"

Comment: Wow! This worked better than Vlad's answer. Reduces the work and characters. Very grateful, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Do you want something like this?

```
let numberA: Float = 1.234
let numberB: Float = 7.000

func getStringFromNumber(number: Float) -> String {
    if number - Float(Int(number)) == 0 {
        return String("\(Int(number))")
    } else {
        return String("\(number)")
    }
}

print(getStringFromNumber(numberA)) // console output: 1.234
print(getStringFromNumber(numberB)) // console output: 7
```

Comment: This worked so well! I'm very grateful for your answer, exactly what I wanted. Thank you!